# Why can't i use fig.cap - Latex through Sweave + Knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I'm very new to Latex, and I'm trying my way on creating a graph with a figure caption.

Now when I try to add `fig.cap` in the chunk heading (second chunk) I get the error

> Latex error: Not in outer par mode

My code

```
<<echo = FALSE>>= 
source("analysis.R")

repoData <- readRDS("data/repoData.rds")

  a4width<- 8.3
  a4height<- 11.7
@
\begin{figure}[h]
<<echo = FALSE, fig.width= a4width, fig.height=0.35*a4height>>=
G2(repoData)
@
\end{figure}


## ---- G2 ----
G2 <- function(df) {
  # For inflation graph  
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = Percent)) +

    geom_line(colour = "firebrick") +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Repo rate") +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1))

  return(plot)

}
```

Why does this happen and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should omit the `\begin{figure}` (not shown in your MWE) and `\end{figure}` from your Sweave file; when you specify `fig.cap` they are generated automatically by `knitr` (and redundantly, in the case of your MWE, leading to the error).

If you need to specify other LaTeX figure options, see the "Plot" section of the [knitr chunk options documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/): in particular, if you want to use position "h", use `fig.pos="h"` in your chunk options, as indicated by

> `fig.pos`: (''; character) a character string for the figure position arrangement to be used in `\begin{figure}[fig.pos]`

Comment: Ahh. But how can I specify where the figure is to be put then? Because I need the [h] ("here") that comes after \{figure}.